# What slows down this histogram query?

Tags: oracle, optimization, plsql

I have a table `my_link_t` with columns `t.weight` type `number` and categorical `speedcat` type integer values from 2 to 8. I want to split data in buckets from min=0, max=0.6, step = 0.001 and build a 3D plot to see weight distribution per each category.

initial data looks like
weight speedcat
0.0234 2
0.8643 6
0.1854 7
(hundred million more entries with weight between 0 and 0.6 and speedcat between 2 and 8)

These queries return correct results and complete in less than a minute each:

```
--repeat for each variable. Here we loook for speedcat =8
--It takes seconds to run this query
create table   histogram_tbl_8  as (
  select  ttt."Start" as bucket_index, ttt.hist_row as bin8  --here
  FROM ((
  SELECT  Bucket*1 "Start" , Bucket "End", Count(Bucket) hist_row
  FROM (SELECT WIDTH_BUCKET (weight, 0, 0.6, 601) Bucket FROM my_link_t  where speedcat=8)
      GROUP BY Bucket ORDER BY Bucket ) ttt   )   );
```

The above query is repeated seven times for `speedcat` in range  `2..8`

```
--if a bin is empty populate it with zero, don't skip it.
create table histogram_output as (
select  tr.bucket_index,
    CASE
        WHEN 1 > (select count(*) from histogram_tbl_2   htm where htm.bucket_index = tr.bucket_index)   THEN 0
        ELSE (select htm.bin2 from histogram_tbl_2   htm where htm.bucket_index =  tr.bucket_index and rownum = 1)
     END
     as b2,
     --same for b3-b7
      CASE
        WHEN 1 > (select count(*) from histogram_tbl_8   htm where htm.bucket_index = tr.bucket_index)   THEN 0
        ELSE     (select htm.bin8    from histogram_tbl_8   htm where htm.bucket_index =  tr.bucket_index and rownum = 1)
     END
     as b8
     FROM  (SELECT LEVEL as bucket_index, 0 as b2, /* 0 as b3, 0 as b4, 0 as b5, 0 as b6, 0 as b7, */ 0 as b8  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 600)  tr
     )
```

Finally

```
      select sum(b2), sum(b3),sum(b4),sum(b5),sum(b6),sum(b7),sum(b8) from histogram_output
       select bucket_index,
              round(b2 * 1000000 / 12921) as  b2, --normalize so that total is 1000000 ppm
              -- repeat for b3-b7
              round(b8 * 1000000 / 6262) as  b8 --normalize so that total is 1000000 ppm
         from histogram_output
```

I get a table like

bin_end speedcat_2 speedcat_3 speedcat_4 .. speedcat_8
0.001
0.002
..
0.599
0.600

Showing ppm of objects within this category and this bin
Now, when I combine queries in

```
-- DONT USE THE EXAMPLE BELOW - it is ineefficient  (runs 2+ hours instead of seconds for the method above)
       SELECT  Bucket_2*1 "Start" , Bucket_2 "End",
       Count(Bucket_2) as b2,
       --same for b3 .. b7
       Count(Bucket_8) as b8

      FROM
      (
          SELECT WIDTH_BUCKET (t2.weight, 0, 0.6, 601) Bucket_2,
                 --same for t3,.. t7
                 WIDTH_BUCKET (t8.weight, 0, 0.6, 601) Bucket_8

           FROM (select weight from my_link_t where  speedcat = 2) t2,
           -- ..speedcat = 3) t3, .. speedcat = 4) t4, etc
            (select weight from my_link_t where  speedcat = 8 ) t8

      )
      GROUP BY Bucket_2 ORDER BY Bucket_2
      ------
```

Query runs several hours (some 500 times longer runtime than individual queries) until I kill it. Books recommend to do all data slicing in SQL. This example suggests that loading data to Java and slicing it there might be better in case of complex queries.

What can cause the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short Answer

Your 7-way Cartesian `JOIN` is going to have some serious performance problems.

## Long Answer

Think in Sets.

I am assuming that your Data Set needs to contain:  speedcat, bucket_index, count(*)

The simple solution for that Data Set is straight forward:

```
select t.speedcat
  , WIDTH_BUCKET (t.weight, 0, 0.6, 601) as bucket_index
  , count(*) N
from my_link_t t
group by t.speedcat, WIDTH_BUCKET (t.weight, 0, 0.6, 601)
```

This is format (x,y,z) is the expect format for most graphing packages.

If you want the results in a "grid" format, then `PIVOT` the results.

```
with data as (
  -- same SELECT as previous answer
  select t.speedcat
    , WIDTH_BUCKET (t.weight, 0, 0.6, 601) as bucket_index
    , count(*) N
  from my_link_t t
  group by t.speedcat, WIDTH_BUCKET (t.weight, 0, 0.6, 601)
)
select *
from data
  pivot (
    sum(N)
    for speedcat in ( 2 as "speedcat_2"
                     ,3 as "speedcat_3"
                     ,4 as "speedcat_4"
                     ,5 as "speedcat_5"
                     ,6 as "speedcat_6"
                     ,7 as "speedcat_7"
                     ,8 as "speedcat_8"
                     )
  )
```

Comment: Just one question: where can one learn this stuff? Textbooks tend to harp on `select * from my_table` for the first 500 pages and then fast forward through other stuff with very little examples. In other words, how can I discover that `pivot` is the answer to my question?

Comment: This query took about a second to complete. Impressive.

Comment: Not every RDBMS supports the `pivot` clause.  Oracle added support back in 11g/11gR2.  MS-SQL had in in (i think) MSSQL 2015 (or 2005).  I don't think MySQL supports it.  You will find it in the documentation for you RDBMS of choice.  So, you will find it if you Read The Fine Manual of your RDBMS of choice. (remember, "database agnostic code is a myth", pick an RDBMS and use everyone of its features)

Comment: Reading oracle docs in alphabetical order of keywords is a piecemeal learning. And their docs aren't very clear. But if there is no better way I will do it.